# How to use GROUP BY clause with COUNT(*)

Tags: oracle, count

I have two tables on Oracle database, one is named departments_table and the other is locations_table. The departments.table has dep_id, dep_name, location_id, staff_id, employer_id. The locations table consists of location_id, city_id, streetname_id and postcode_id. How do I calculate the number of departments  that each location has?

This is the code below is what I have tried to replicate but have been unsuccessful. The error message below that is what shows once the code has submitted.

```
SELECT dep_name, location_id,
COUNT(*)
FROM departments_table
WHERE location_id => 1
GROUP BY dep_name; 

The results of this is an error, " not a single group function "
```

Comment: You don't state the version of your Oracle-DB. In Oracle 12c and 11.2 you can use LISTAGG to get the count and the names of the departments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many departments are in each location, then you must group by location, not by department name, right? Let's start with that.

Then, you don't need ANYTHING about the individual departments in the output of the query, do you? You just need the location id and the count of departments.

```
select   location_id, count(*) as cnt
from     departments_table
group by location_id
;
```

This does most of the work. You may want to add the location name (city, address, etc.), which is/are stored elsewhere - in the locations_table. So you will need a join. And there may be locations in that table that are not, in fact, the location of any department (their id doesn't appear in the departments_table at all). If so, you would need an OUTER join. Also for those departments you probably want to show a count of 0 (rather than `null`) - you can "fix" that with the `nvl()` function. So you will end up with something like

```
select l.*, nvl(g.cnt, 0) as department_count
from   locations_table l
       left outer join
       ( select   location_id, count(*) as cnt
         from     departments_table
         group by location_id
       ) g
           on l.location_id = g.location_id
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. i have since come up with the following:  SELECT location_id, city, COUNT(department_id) 
FROM OEHR_DEPARTMENTS, OEHR_DEPARTMENTS WHERE OEHR_locations.location_id = OEHR_departments.location_id ORDER BY city;        However I get the response 'Column ambiguously defined'. (OEHR is the table name)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.location_id, l.city, COUNT(d.DEPARTMENT_ID)                                                    

FROM OEHR_LOCATIONS l, OEHR_DEPARTMENTS d WHERE l.location_id = d.location_id                           

GROUP BY l.location_id, l.city ORDER BY l.city;
```

This method works. I created aliases and made minor changes. OEHR stands for the table names so ignore that.